# Simple sql table and data generator

Tags: sql

My girlfriend, who's studying economics, has a "informative systems" exams. Part of the exam is about the sql language. It's pretty basic stuff, only selects. She has a plethora of written test cases out of her textbook.

I'm helping her with the exercises, but I'd love to have a simple program **(linux or mac or, even better, web-based**) where to input table structures with relations (foreign keys), have it generate a sample data set and being able to query it with the standard sql language.

Comment: You can even use SQL with ADO and Excel.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server you could try Red Gate's [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_data_generator/index.htm). It's not a free product, but there's a 14 day trial, which I guess is enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps ms sql server express and a trial edition of [RedGate SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm)